# Преобразование строки в байтовый массив

Tags: c++, c

Имеется строка "0A12110023...". Нужно преобразовать ее в байтовый массив следующего вида: 0x0A 0x12 0x11 0x00 0x23 и так далее

Comment: А где кусок кода, который вы написали сами?

Comment: 1) читаете входную строку по 2 символа 2) переводите эти символы в число (`"0A" => 0x0A` etc) 3) число записываете в массив 4) меняете тег `C++` на `C` :-)

Answer (score 3):

Все, нашлось решение:

```
char *hexstring = "deadbeef10203040b00b1e50";
int i;
unsigned int bytearray[12];
uint8_t str_len = strlen(hexstring);

for (i = 0; i < (str_len / 2); i++) {
    sscanf(hexstring + 2*i, "%02x", &bytearray[i]);
}
```

Comment: `uint8_t str_len` o_O

Answer (score 2):

Пока тег [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) не заменили на [c](/questions/tagged/c) предложу соответствующее решение:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    const std::string hexs = "deadbeef10203040b00b1e50";
    std::vector<int> v;

    std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i < hexs.size() / 2; ++i) {
        v.push_back(std::stoi(hexs.substr(i * 2, 2), nullptr, 16));
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << v[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Взглянуть на результат](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/oOfRIYLjNoVZaz34)</kbd>